# How to access url that requires http authenticate in c/c++/command line?

Tags: http-authentication

```
http://admin:123456@192.168.1.178/videostream.cgi
```

To access a url that doesn't require http authenticate it's quite easy:

```
telnet 192.168.1.178 80
Get /videostream.cgi HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html;text/plain

User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.13) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.5.13
Connection: close
```

But how to specify `admin:123456`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) or [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

It can be educational to use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), or some other LAN sniffer, to watch what a browser and server do when you access a URL with embedded credentials such as your http://admin:123456@192.168.1.178/videostream.cgi

Comment: Is it possible to save the video stream into a file by command line?

Comment: As Wyatt Anderson says, there are tools like curl that are useful for this sort of thing. I mostly use `wget` which is similar to `curl`. For example `wget http://admin:123456@192.168.1.178/videostream.cgi` or `wget --http-user admin --http-password 123456 http://192.168.1.178/videostream.cgi`.

Answer (score 1):

For [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), you specify the username and password as `username:password`, then Base64-encode it and use it as an argument to the `Authentication` header:

```
Authorization: Basic YXNkZjoxMjM0
```

`YXNkZjoxMjM0` decodes to `asdf:1234`; I used `curl -u adsf:1234` (specifying the username "asdf" and password "1234") to produce this result.

Comment: Is it possible to save the video stream into a file by command line?

Comment: You might try just using `curl`: `curl -O -u USERNAME:PASSWORD url` would save the output to a file. Check out the manpage for `curl` for the complete list of options.

Comment: No curl,only telnet is allowed.BTW,I tried to use curl to deal with stream before,but seems not working,it can only deal with simple resources but not continuous streams.

Comment: Hmm. Tricky. So you can *only* use `telnet` to do this? Are you on Linux or Windows? You could try redirecting the output of `telnet` to a file. It looks like [this guy](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4412/use-curl-to-save-an-mp3-stream) has some advice for saving MP3 streams with `curl`... but if you're really only restricted to using `telnet` you might have a harder time.

Comment: From a firewall point of view, using curl (or wget) is indistinguishable from using telnet to port 80. I would use Wireshark to see how the service at your URL is streaming data. Perhaps it serves up HTML with some embedded links to other object URLs that do the streaming?